# What kind of bean in Java EE 7?

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb

without using @stateful, @stateless, and @singleton in session bean in Java EE 7, by default what type of bean is it? For instance,

```
@Named
public class HelloService {

public String hello () {
   return "Hello";
}
}
```

Is this a stateful, stateless or singleton bean, without explicitly annotating it with a state?

Comment: It's a CDI bean. http://cdi-spec.org/

Comment: It says "A well-defined lifecycle for stateful objects bound to lifecycle contexts, where the set of contexts is extensible". Does mean HelloService is a stateful session bean?

Comment: By the way, is this a session bean? How to determine whether an annotated class is a session bean or not?

Comment: No. It's a CDI bean. A session bean is annotated with Stateless or Stateful.

Comment: @JB: What's the scope of this bean? RequestScoped, ViewScoped, SessionScoped, ApplicationScoped.

Comment: I gave you the link of the spec. Read it. It's explained. The spec has a table of contents. Your browser can search for keywords. It took me literally 10 seconds to find the chapter named "Default scope": http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.1/cdi-spec.html#default_scope

Comment: Is this CDI specification JBOSS specific, or generally applies to all JEE components?

Comment: CDI is part of Java EE. It is not JBoss specific. Weld is the JBoss implementation of CDI. What I linked to is the CDI spec.

Comment: Thanks. A lot to be learned.

Comment: "The default scope if none is specified; it means that an object exists to serve exactly one client (bean) and has the same lifecycle as that client (bean)." - so says the oracle cup of java at https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/cdi-basic008.htm#GJBBK

Answer (score 2):

It is a simple `Java Bean` (not EJB), which if CDI is enabled can be injected in other beans, and is available for jsp/jsf pages via EL under name `helloService`. **It is not stateless, stateful or any EJB**. EJBs have services managed by the container (like transaction, security etc), CDI beans have not.

Bean is a session bean, if it has been annotated using `@Stateless, @Stateful, @Singleton` or described using descriptor `ejb-jar.xml`.

Comment: Must a session bean be an EJB?

Comment: @ling You are confusing EJB session beans (stateless and stateful) with CDI `@SessionScoped` beans (POJOs). The former are mostly used for transactional business logic, the latter are just objects associated with the HTTP session.

Answer (score 0):

In Java EE 7, CDI is enabled by default (without beans.xml). So, it's basically a **CDI managed bean**.